# How can i adjust the positioning of two html elements?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adjust the position of two HTML Elements. I have one HTML element to display the "ASCII" generated text. The other, to display an  tag with a HREF link. I want the  tag to be displayed underneath the printed "ASCII" text. However, it seems to be printing next to it, which isn't what I want.

My HTML code is as follows:

```css
    *, *:before, *:after {
      border: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
      font: 16px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
      line-height: 1;
      background-color: black;
    }
    
    .container {
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      align-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .bypass {
      text-align: center;
      color: linear-gradient(to top, #e7343d 50%, #e7343d 50%);
      color:transparent;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      background-clip: text;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .rainbow {
    
      background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #e7343d 50%, #61d6d6 50%);
      color:transparent;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      background-clip: text;
    }
    
    .ascii {
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Brrrrrr</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
      <style>
             @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=VT323&display=swap');
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="container rainbow">
        <pre class="ascii ascii-0">
           ______            __               _
          / ____/_  ______  / /_  ____  _____(_)___ _
         / __/ / / / / __ \/ __ \/ __ \/ ___/ / __ `/
        / /___/ /_/ / /_/ / / / / /_/ / /  / / /_/ /
       /_____/\__,_/ .___/_/ /_/\____/_/  /_/\__,_/
                  /_/
                  </pre>
        <div id="wrapper">
          <div id="Content-container">
            <nav class="bypass" id="main-nav"></nav>
            </nav>
            <nav id="social-media-nav">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a id="bypass" class="bypass" href="https://google.com/">Home</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
        <pre>
        </pre>
        <pre id="text"></pre>
      </div>src="script.js"&gt;<!-- partial -->
       
      <script src="./script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Add `flex-direction: column;` to your `.container` styles. Flex direction by default is `row`

Comment: @disinfor I just tried that, whilst it does center it, it posts the text above the ascii art.

Comment: Not sure what you're seeing, but that worked here in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kotq0w94/

Comment: @disinfor Yes, that works without JavaScript. Please take a look here [link(https://jsfiddle.net/jy9b5etw/1/)

Comment: You need to update your snippet to include your Javascript. How could we possibly know that's what you were working with if it's not in your question and you didn't tag the question with a javascript tag?

Comment: Add `#wrapper {
      order: 3;
    }` to your CSS. That will do what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use flexbox order to order item between DOM-ordered items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168052/use-flexbox-order-to-order-item-between-dom-ordered-items)

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to add that in. No, that didn't help in this situation.

Comment: I tested with your fiddle adding that line of CSS and that moved your animated ASCII above the `home` link: https://jsfiddle.net/vrdzLbej/

Answer (score 1):

you can use the following code to print your text on next line

<strike>**Remove this code**</strike>

```
.ascii {
   display: none;
 }
```

**Add this code**

```
.rainbow { flex-flow: row wrap; }
```

**Add a new div with between two elements**

```
<pre class="ascii ascii-0">..</pre>
<div class="break"></div>
<div id="wrapper">..<div>
```

**Add CSS to the new div**

```
.break { 
  flex-basis: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

### Update

---

since I got the js file attached in the project, this can be resolved with following steps

step 1:
move the div with id = text up and add a div with class .break

```
<pre class="ascii ascii-0">...</pre>
<pre id="text">...</pre>
<div class="break">...</div>
<div id="wrapper">...</div>
```

step 2:
Add the .break class and add code to .rainbow class as above.
Do not remove

```
.ascii { display: none }
```

[Check the Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/amodshinde/Lz209epa/)

Comment: This appears to print "Euphoria" twice, unless I miss understood. [link](https://lushy.dev/384e9igjhrito/v3/)

Comment: okay so I didn't know this had js associated with it
can you share the js file in your question?

Comment: Yes! I apologize. [link(https://jsfiddle.net/jy9b5etw/1/)

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it and also attached my jsfiddle link

Comment: @cosmokid Please click the checkmark button to the left of the question if this resolved the issue and close the question